# Prep work for Paver Patio

Tags: patio, pavers, wet, excavation, base

We have excavated for a paver patio and walkway at our home. It’s a fairly large area and we missed getting the base laid and compacted before the weather turned cold. We now have a large dirt area that’s been laser graded and unfortunately it hasn’t stopped raining long enough for the area to be dry so that we can lay the fabric, base and then compact. Would it be harmful for us to lay the fabric, and put 1-3” of the base layer down just to prevent it from being muddy all winter and then let it dry out in the spring, compact and finish when the weather is nicer and the ground is no longer frozen?
[image][image]

Comment: compacted crushed rock is your first layer over the dirt, since it is muddy and soft you will need more of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the fabric and base as you intended. Any rain would only help compact it without it being constantly muddy.

Comment: Agreed.  Actually letting the dirt and base 'settle in' over time would actually make it more stable.

Comment: So the consensus is to just place the fabric and start compacting the 6” base in multiple lifts now even with it being wet? Then I can run over it in the spring with the transit and fix any settling with more base before laying pavers in the spring?

Comment: Correct.  If I were in your situation, that is what I would do.

Comment: Awesome. Much appreciated!

Comment: Looks pretty squishy now.  You don't want to put your base on top of squishy subgrade.